# make private fields visible within inherited subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation, superclass

I am pretty new to Java, so that my question will be rather naive, I think.

For a project of mine, I decided to code in Java and I'd like making use of the **encapsulation** and **inheritance** concepts.

Staying short, I'd like to know if there is any chance to make private fields from the superclass being somehow visible from within the subclass, although still not accessible by the user?

Comment: To be short. No, it can be done.

I would suggest you to read chapter 2 from SCJP book. It has an awesome explanation on encapsulation and inheritance.

Comment: Everything is visible and displayed in the project structure, and accessible if it has a corresponding access modifier.

Comment: Ask yourself _why_ do we want to restrict access? And then _why_ do we want to allow access in this particular case?... it seems likely that you can avoid wanting to do this by modifying the design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing `protected`.

See [*Controlling Access to Members of a Class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) from the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In short it is not possible. The closest option is making it protected but now that field can be accessed from other classes in same package even if they do not extend the super class.

Another option could be accessing those fields from subclass using reflection but it would be really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the fields in the superclass *protected* instead of *private*. This would make the fields accessible to subclasses as well as other classes in the same package, but not to the world.

You may find this tutorial helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Change private access modifier in to at least protected. But if you do this, the variable can access inside the package. Not only sub class.
2. Define get method in parent class for private variable and use super.getX() in sub class. Further, you can set get method access modifier to protected to avoid access get method from classes, outside the package.